# Install npm package into Azure Bot Service

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am trying to integrate bot analytics (https://github.com/Botanalytics/botanalytics-microsoftbotframework-middleware) into an azure bot service.

However, as I am very new to node.js, I have no idea how to install the package using npm in azure. What I did is to enter "npm install botanalytics-microsoftbotframework-middleware" into azure cloud shell.

However, when I checked node_modules and package.json (screenshot below) folders, it was not shown there.

This should be quite a noob question, but I am limited in my knowledge to resolve myself...

Thanks!

[image]

[Edit]

```
{
  "name": "luisbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^3.7.0",
    "botbuilder-azure": "3.0.2",
    "botanalytics-microsoftbotframework-middleware": "0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
      "restify": "^4.3.0"
  },  
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the NPM module name and version to your package.json dependencies section and save the file. The Bot Service will detect the changes and run npm install for you.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work. I added it to the package.json > dependencies, but that seem to be under the luis package? It did not install the package I need. What do u think? Thanks